# $\lim_{x\to\infty}$ when the function is defined only on a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I know that, for example, if
$$f(x)=\frac{e^{-\sin x}}{x}$$
for all real $x\gt 0$, then $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$.

However, how do we compute $\lim_{x\to\infty}$ when the function is defined only on a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$? If the domain of $g$ is the interval $[0,\pi]$ and $g=\sin$ on $[0,\pi]$, is it true that
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=0?$$

It's true if and only if for every $\varepsilon\gt 0$ there exists $M\gt 0$ such that $|g(x)|\lt \varepsilon$ whenever $x\gt M$.

And it seems that for $x\in [0,\pi]$ we can make $|g(x)|$ arbitrarily close to $0$ and at the same time, we don't get to choose from any $x\gt\pi$. Or is this a misinterpretation?

Edit to make this clear:
The definition of limit I am using is:

If the domain of $f$ is $D$, then
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L\iff \forall \varepsilon \gt 0\, \exists M\gt 0 \,\forall x\in D:\, x\gt M\implies |f(x)-L|\lt \varepsilon .$$

Comment: I see this as a misinterpretation.  For a finite $x_0$, in order to compute the $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x)$, although $f(x)$ doesn't have to be defined **at** $(x = x_0)$ it must be defined in some *neighborhood* around $x_0$, that is $\{x ~: ~0 < |x - x_0| < \delta ~: ~\delta > 0\}.$  Now, $+\infty$ is not a number, but rather a symbol for unbounded growth.  In order for $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x)$ to exist, there must exist an $x_0$ such that for all $x > x_0, f(x)$ is defined.

Comment: @user2661923 Does that follow from the $\varepsilon$,$\delta$ (or rather $\varepsilon$,$M$) definition I gave?

Comment: Yes.  More specifically, assuming that you are learning from a book/class, there should be very explicit $\epsilon ~\delta$ definitions of what it means for a limit to exist.

Comment: @user2661923 I'm trying to figure out how it follows from the $\varepsilon$,$M$.

Comment: Very good point.  Actually, it depends on how the limit is defined.  I have seen a definition where the constraint of $~\forall x > M~$ is only applied if the domain actually is unbounded.  With such a definition, you are right that the domain itself could be bounded, and still have the $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ exist.  You need to consult your book/class for the very explicit definition.

Comment: @user2661923 So just to make this clear: If the $\forall x\gt M (x\in\mathbb{R}\,\text{and not only the domain of}\,g)$ thing is not required and we just use the definition given in my post, then $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=0$?

Comment: To tell you the truth, I am not sure.  Under your (somewhat bizarre) hypothetical, you would have that $\lim_{x\to \infty} g(x) = 0$ and also have that $\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x) = 5000~$ or any other value that you want.  This conflicts with the basic idea that a function can not converge to more than one limit.  Again, I think that you need to consult your book/class for the explicit definition.  I especially recommend asking your teacher.

Comment: @user2661923 But how could it be possible that $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=5000$? It would mean that (by the given definition) for every $\varepsilon\gt 0$ there exists $M\gt 0$ such that $|g(x)-5000|\lt \varepsilon$ whenever $x\gt M$ which doesn't seem to be correct to me. $|g(x)-5000|$ certainly cannot be made arbitrarily small when $x\in [0,\pi]$.

Comment: Let $D$ denote the domain of $f(x).$  If there exists an $M$ such that $f(x)$ is not defined for any $x > M$, then the following is true: $\forall \epsilon, ~\exists M > 0~$ such that $\forall x \in \{ [x: x > M] \cap D \},~ |g(x) - 5000| < \epsilon.$   In order to prove the assertion is false, you would have to find a counter example.  But you can't find any counter example because $\{ [x: x > M] \cap D \}$ is the empty set.

Comment: I repeat : I am on shaky ground here.  I advise consulting your book/class/teacher.

Comment: @user2661923 Alright but aren't you just using the definition of the limit with the "unbounded" constraint $\forall x\gt M$?

Comment: Yes, what else can I do.  If you want me to use a different definition, specify the definition that you want me to use.

Comment: @user2661923 Here it is: Let $f(x)$ be a function defined only on a finite subset of $\mathbb{R}$ (*$x$ is constrained to be in that subset*). Then we say that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L$ if and only if for every real $\varepsilon\gt 0$ there is a real $M\gt 0$ such that $|f(x)-L|\lt \varepsilon$ whenever $x\gt M$.

Comment: The constraint in your question is ambiguous.  Is there an $M > 0$ such that the domain of $f(x)$ does not intersect with $\{x ~: ~x > M\}?$  If so, then my previous example re $g(x) \to 5000$ as $x \to \infty$ applies.  Alternatively, if for any $M > 0$, the domain of $f(x)$ does intersect with $\{x ~: ~x > M\}$, then my previous analysis re $g(x) \to 5000$ would not apply.

Comment: I updated the question - you mean a *bounded* set, not a *finite* set.  A *finite* set would be one with a finite number of points in it, like $\{1,2,3\}$.

Comment: Not going to post as an answer since it's probably more advanced than the OP's current level: but in the context of limits I tend to interpret $\infty$ as the filter generated by $\{ (M, \infty) \mid M \in \mathbb{R} \}$.  But then, in the case of a bounded domain, that is no longer a filter since it contains the empty set, so taking the limit of a function over that nonfilter becomes nonsensical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By usual definitions, if the domain of $g$ is $[0,\pi]$, then $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x)$ is undefined.

More generally, the definition of $\lim_{x \to y} g(x)$ as stated in most books requires that $y$ is a limit point of the domain of $g$.  In the case of $y = +\infty$, this means that for every $M > 0$, there must exist $x \in (M, +\infty)$ which is in the domain of $g$.  This is equivalent to saying that the domain is unbounded above in $\mathbb{R}$, and is consistent with the usual topological definition of "limit point" with respect to the usual topology on the extended reals $[-\infty, +\infty]$.

Comment: That definition seems to be different from the following: If the domain of $f$ is $D$, then
$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L\iff \forall \varepsilon \gt 0 \exists M\gt 0 \forall x\in D:\, x\gt M\implies |f(x)-L|\lt \varepsilon .$ Is $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=0$ under this setting?

Comment: @Nomas: Yes, it is: we can for instance take $M=10$ and then any statement starting $\forall x \in D : x > M \implies \dots$ becomes vacuously true.  So $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x)=0$ is a true statement.  Likewise, as user2661923 has pointed out, $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = 5000$ is also a true statement.  This means your definition does not define $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ as a unique number, and therefore, I would argue, it is not the "right" definition. Certainly it is not equivalent to the definition given in most carefully written books.

Comment: @Nomas: I think the most likely explanation is that the author of your book carelessly forgot to include a restriction on $g$ that its domain should have $+\infty$ as a limit point.    Or, that this is a "standing assumption" on $g$ stated elsewhere in the text, that you may have overlooked.

Comment: And what is the result of $\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x)$ when we use the "right" definition instead?

Comment: @Nomas: "Undefined", as I said, or if you prefer, "does not exist".  The usual "right" definition applies only when $+\infty$ is a limit point of the domain, and that condition is not met in your example.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, the definition given in my post is always equivalent to the "right" definition except  when $\infty$ is not a limit point of the domain.

Comment: @Nomas: Correct.  Indeed, I would say the "right" definition could be stated as just the conjuction ($\land$) of the right-hand side of your definition with the statement $\forall M > 0\,\exists x \in D : x > M$.